# Every entry node is in the USA

Tags: circuit, guard-node

With this tor version (I can't tell you because it isn't shown anywhere in the browser) every entry node is from the USA only. I'm always trying to avoid any node from USA or little britain. But it looks impossible now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should set these settings in your tor config:

```
StrictNodes 1
ExcludeNodes {us}
```